# VBA CommandBar does not execute the OnAction subrutine

Tags: vba, ms-access

The following code is not doing anything in my Access application.
I expected to run the Subrutine **TestMacro**.

It shows up the menu but not reaction at all after selecting.

Any idea?

```
Private Sub Check_Status_Click()
  Set The_Menu = CreateSubMenu
  The_Menu.ShowPopup
End Sub


Function CreateSubMenu() As CommandBar
  Const pop_up_menu_name = "Pop-up Menu"
  Dim the_command_bar As CommandBar
  Dim the_command_bar_control As CommandBarControl

  Set the_command_bar = CommandBars.Add(Name:=pop_up_menu_name, Position:=msoBarPopup, MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=False)
  Set the_command_bar_control = the_command_bar.Controls.Add
  the_command_bar_control.Caption = "Run Macro Hello World!"
  the_command_bar_control.OnAction = "TestMacro"
  Set CreateSubMenu = the_command_bar
End Function


Public Sub TestMacro()
  MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `TestMacro` is in common module, not in the form's one.

Also before adding new menu delete existing one if it exists:

```
On Error Resume Next
CommandBars.Item(pop_up_menu_name).Delete
On Error GoTo 0
```

Otherwise, you'll get an error

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Sergey, but unfortunatly it still does not work.

Any other idea?